# On my dev server, only the last query runs when turning off autocommit or using a transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, mariadb

I have a weird issue with PHP and MySQL. I'm running MariaDB 10.4.8 on my development server.

In order to avoid race conditions or increase performance of a large number of updates, I queue the updates by `$db->AUTOCOMMIT(false)` and then `$db->commit()` or `$db->AUTOCOMMIT(true)` once I'm done. Now, this works fine on our production server, but ever since setting up the new development server, it seems that only the last query run in the loop during this is executed.

For example (forgive the lack of a prepared statement):

```php
$db->autocommit(FALSE);
while ($interactions = $recentInteractions->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $db->query("UPDATE $tempTableName SET recentInteractions = {$interactions["interactionCount"]} WHERE itemID = {$interactions["itemID"]}");
}
$db->autocommit(TRUE);
```

or

```php
$db->begin_transaction();
while ($interactions = $recentInteractions->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $db->query("UPDATE $tempTableName SET recentInteractions = {$interactions["interactionCount"]} WHERE itemID = {$interactions["itemID"]}");
}
$db->commit();
```

On the production server, this runs all of the queries perfectly fine. On the dev box, it only seems to run the last one. Prod and dev have fairly similar software versions/stack, though I was unable to match 1-to-1 while setting up.

#### PHP-MySQL drivers and MariaDB versions:

Prod: php71u-mysqlnd.x86_64 (ius)

Dev: php-mysqlnd.x86_64 (remi-php73)

Prod: MariaDB-server.x86_64 (10.2.24)

Dev: MariaDB-server.x86_64 (10.4.8)

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: So if you set autocommit to true in your first line, all your updates work on dev, and if you set it to false only the last one works? Have you verfied the loop runs in those cases (e.g. by echoing something)? Do you have errorhandling/catch errors (that may do an implicit rollback but continue the loop or something)?

Comment: @Solarflare Yes, that's correct. I have dropped in error_log statements to check that the loop is happening and that the queries are built properly. No exception handling/error-checking on the loops, I just need to run a large number of UPDATEs quickly.

Comment: There are 3 cases.  False..COMMIT; False..True; BEGIN..COMMIT.  Please build a table with those 3 as rows and columns labeled 10.2 and 10.4.  Inside say good or bad for each of the 6 cells.  I am confused by the Question and the Comments.

Comment: i just ran into the same issue using mariadb 10.4.8-1
solved it by downgrading to 10.3

Comment: @ManfredWuits That's curious...I'm going to give that a try soon and see what happens.

Comment: @ManfredWuits Update: That did it! 10.4 does not seem to be working properly with transactions. I'll check later to see if there's an active bug report on it.